# Mapping polygon vs points within each polygon into one table using QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I have 2 layers: 1 is for points (GPS), another is the polygon containing administrative borders in my country.
I would like to know for each polygon *(the district/ state.) the list of points that fall within that polygon .
So for example my desired output is

District 1  Point 1
District 1 Point 2
District 2 Point 3
District 2 Point 4
...
District N Point N

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Try "join by location" (vector menu)